# Android - Confirm app exit with toast

Tags: android, exit, toast, back, confirm

I'm new to Android development and I want it so when the user presses the back button on the main activity, a toast message appears with a "confirm exit by pressing the back button again" message. How would I do this? This is what I have so far:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    Toast s = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    s.show();
    wait();

    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        finish();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the toast showing? What is/isn't working? It may be better to have a counter in there and if the counter = 2 then finish. Or use a dialog instead of a toast

Comment: Best solution in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/android-clicking-twice-the-back-button-to-exit-activity

Answer (score 21):

I would just save the time of the backpress and then compare the time of the latest press to the new press.

```
long lastPress;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(currentTime - lastPress > 5000){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        lastPress = currentTime;
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

You can also dismiss the toast when the app the back press is confirmed (cred @ToolmakerSteve):

```
long lastPress;
Toast backpressToast;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(currentTime - lastPress > 5000){
        backpressToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        backpressToast.show();
        lastPress = currentTime;
    } else {
        if (backpressToast != null) backpressToast.cancel();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was wanting to do! With a toast rather than a dialogbox :)

Comment: this is the proper solution for those who are wandering on many other topics!

Comment: Also see user8218's enhancement of this, which removes the toast as soon as user presses back the second time:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18654014/199364  HOWEVER user8218's answer is WRONG as written; submitting a change that I explain in a comment on that; hopefully my change will be accepted.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve updated my answer, please verify that it looks good.

Comment: Looks great!  Thanks.  (No need for people to look at user8218's answer now; this answer is complete. Thanks to user8218 for the idea. If you like that addition, consider upvoting that answer also.)

Comment: An alternative answer to consider [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15728990/199364). I haven't decided yet which approach I prefer.

Comment: I have 2 remarks about this solution.

First, the toast duration is 2000ms for `LENGTH_SHORT` and 3500ms for `LENGTH_LONG`. So maybe it would be better to use the corresponding value instead of 5000. The documentation says that _this time could be user-definable_. I couldn't find how to retrieve the actual value, which would have been better.

Second, if you use a Drawer Menu for example, `super.onBackPressed()` will go back to the previous fragment and won't exit the app. So it's better to explicitly close the app with `finish()` instead of relying on `super.onBackPressed()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
private long mLastPress = 0;
const int TOAST_DURATION = 5000;
Toast onBackPressedToast;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (currentTime - mLastPress > TOAST_DURATION) {
        onBackPressedToast = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.press_once_again_to_exit, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        onBackPressedToast.show();
        mLastPress = currentTime;
    } else {
        if (onBackPressedToast != null) {
            onBackPressedToast.cancel();  //Difference with previous answer. Prevent continuing showing toast after application exit.
            onBackPressedToast = null;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the previous answer the toast is only created on the first back press and that toast is not canceled in your answer.

Comment: [Submitted as an edit] Can fix this (per @Heinrisch' comment) by holding toast in a field outside the method: `Toast onBackPressedToast;` before the method. Then move `onBackPressedToast = Toast...` INSIDE the `if`. In the `else`, protect the cancel with `if (onBackPressedToast != null)`.

Comment: Also need `const int TOAST_DURATION = 5000;`

Comment: ... and might as well set toast variable to null, when we cancel it.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Why should we set the toast to null if the app will quit anyway?

Comment: @Thomas - you are right, that is not necessary, given that we know the app is exiting. (Its a habit to clean up resources of variables outside of the method.)

Answer (score 1):

work perfectly in my case

```
private static long back_pressed;

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
        if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) 
               super.onBackPressed();
        else 
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: Please explain the differences from the most-upvoted answer that existed two years before this. What is different, and how is this an improvement over that answer?  Also, what justifies making this a new answer, rather than a comment on that answer? (IMHO, it better serves future readers to suggest *small* changes in comments on an existing answer, rather than creating a whole new answer.)

Answer (score 0):

In newer version you can use the snackbar instead of toast.

```
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
...
Snackbar.make(content, "Click BACK again to exit", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setAction("Action", null).show();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

After having to implement the same behaviour many a times, decided to go aboiut building a library for the same : [`DoubleBackPress Android Library`](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/DoubleBackPress). It provides many easy to use templates and the double back press behaviour without all the hassle.

Just do :

```
// set the ToastDisplay to be shown on FirstBackPress
FirstBackPressAction firstBackPressAction = new ToastDisplay().standard(this);

// set the Action on DoubleBackPress
DoubleBackPressAction doubleBackPressAction = new DoubleBackPressAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionCall() {
        finish();
    }
};

// setup DoubleBackPress behaviour
DoubleBackPress doubleBackPress = new DoubleBackPress()
        .withDoublePressDuration(3000)
        .withFirstBackPressAction(firstBackPressAction)
        .withDoubleBackPressAction(doubleBackPressAction);
```

---

Finally, override the onBackPressed with DoubleBackPress behaviour for the back press.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    doubleBackPress.onBackPressed();
}
```

[Example GIF for similar behaviour](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/DoubleBackPress#ToastDisplayExample)

Answer (score 0):

Best and simple solution with Toast

> In Java

```
private Toast exitToast;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (exitToast == null || exitToast.getView() == null || exitToast.getView().getWindowToken() == null) {
        exitToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        exitToast.show();
    } else {
        exitToast.cancel();
        finish();
    }
}
```

> In Kotlin

```
private var exitToast: Toast? = null

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (exitToast == null || exitToast!!.view == null || exitToast!!.view.windowToken == null) {
        exitToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        exitToast!!.show()
    } else {
        exitToast!!.cancel()
        finish()
    }
}
```