# Exit application on pressing back with confirmation

Tags: android, toast, onbackpressed

I need functionality to exit from the complete application while pressing back button.
currently i have a script that ask to press twice to exit application,

in that it finish the current activity but does not exits from application old visited activities are remain same.
here is my code that i am using.

```
int i = 1;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {       
    if (i == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press back once more to exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if(i>1) {
        finish();
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Confirm app exit with toast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006461/android-confirm-app-exit-with-toast)

Comment: As per my knowledge, you can clear stack of your application only not others. Only Android OS task manager can have access of doing it.

Comment: @deepak Sharma you have use flag like FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT in your application.

Comment: @Vlad both questions are different.

Answer (score 0):

please try below code.

**step 1: Create on Constant class**

```
public class Constant
{
    public static int ACT_COUNT=0;
}
```

**step 2:Create BaseActivity class**

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
{
private static long back_pressed;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0)
    {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    Constant.ACT_COUNT++;
    }


   @Override
   public void onBackPressed()
   {
    /** If you want to take confirmation then display Alert here...**/
        if(Constant.ACT_COUNT<=1)
        {
            if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) 
               finish(); /** otherwise directly exit from here...**/
            else 
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Constant.ACT_COUNT--;
    }

}
```

**NOTE: You have to use BaseActivity instead of Activity in your application except login activity and registration activity if it is in your application.**

Answer (score 0):

finish(); doesn't close the application, just finishes the current activity and takes you back to the previous activity running. Instead use System.exit(1);

Answer (score -2):

Get back press work only at second press and notify user to press again to exit.

```
private static long back_pressed;

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
        /** If you want to take confirmation then display Alert here...**/
        if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) 
           finish(); /** otherwise directly exit from here...**/
        else 
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Ref. [Android Snippet](http://www.androidsnippets.com/double-back-press-to-exit)

Comment: nice answer, what a logic.

Comment: This doesn't answer the "question."

Comment: @323go What is problem with answer?

Comment: The question was why it doesn't exit, not how to exit with confirmation. Please read the question.

Comment: @323go  If he wants to take confirmation then show AlertDialog `onBackPressed()` then Exit on `Yes`, but he want to press again then exit so my answer is correct. you can add your answer if you have other solution.

Comment: Hey may i know why downvoting my answer? Is there any problem?