# how to prevent navigation to previous screen and show exit confirm message on back button tap

Tags: android

i am creating a quiz app in witch: when use choose an answer user will be navigate to next screen.

**what i want begins here:**

i want to prevent user to go back to previous screen,

if user try to go back to previous screen by taping back button, a exit confirm message should appear.

if user choose "OK" the app should close and if user choose "CANCEL / (Continue Quiz)" the app should continue from current screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override in your activity [onBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) in this way

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this).create();
    dlg.setCancelable(false);
    dlg.setTitle("CLOSE");
    dlg.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    dlg.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    dlg.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "CLOSE APP", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            YourActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    dlg.show();
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using `ActivityName.super.onBackPressed()` instead of `finish()` in the onClick for the positive button.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `onBackPressed()` function in your Activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // code for displaying confirm message here
}
```

This answer has sample code for creating a confirmation dialog box: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6413736/379245