# onBackPressed in Activity

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I am new to android and i was actually try to use onBackPressed using if method.

For example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

if( pressed back button... ){

// action
}

}
```

Overriding onBackPressed method didnt help me at all

Comment: At least ask question properly...

Comment: see this link you can understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413700/android-proper-way-to-use-onbackpressed

Comment: i want to use if method. Can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // your after back press code
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: thank you
can i use key event using if method inside oncreate?