# Android Studio: @Override "Annotations are not allowed here"

Tags: java, android, annotations, overriding

I want to implement the ...

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     }
```

However, I get an error message saying, **"Annotations are not allowed here"**. I need this method to be implemented here. Is there an alternative?

```
public class supbreh extends Appbreh

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intent_breh);

 if (myBundle != null) {

        String name =  myBundle.getString("workout");
        ShowDetails(name);
    }
}

 private void ShowAbDetails(String mName) {


    if(mName.equals("abs1")){


        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {  //"Not Allowed here"

        }

}
```

Comment: you cant write method inside method move this  `@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {  //"Not Allowed here"

        }`  out of method

Comment: Is there a way to assign the back button on my android phone its own local variable?

Comment: What does that even mean? ^

Comment: Illegal usage of the method. If your Appbreh class is extended by Activity, you can override the method with-in class. It's basic OOP concept.

Comment: could you demonstrate the syntax? @YasirTahir

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21841637/5392825

Comment: @TimCastelijns  Every button created from the UI has an id, right? Well, what would be the "Id" for the Back Button on the android phone

Comment: *Every button created from the UI has an id, right?* No they don't. And the back button is not a UI button

Answer (score 1):

```
void onBackPressed ()
```

> Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back
>   key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity,
>   but you can override this to do whatever you want.

In here you can't declare this method inside another method .

Only override it in that one Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();  
}
```

**FYI**

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(IndividualAbsWorkout.this, IndividualAbsWorkout.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to start a new activity with void onBackPressed()?

Comment: as in .. Intent nextScreen = new Intent(IndividualAbsWorkout.this, IndividualAbsWorkout.class);
                    nextScreen.putExtra("abWorkout", "abs2");
                    startActivity(nextScreen);

Answer (score 0):

You can override onBackPressed as normal and call the method in ShowAbDetails() method like below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_intent_breh);

 if (myBundle != null) {
    String name =  myBundle.getString("workout");
    ShowDetails(name);
 }

}

private void ShowAbDetails(String mName) {

    if(mName.equals("abs1")){
      onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {  
   // your logic here
}
```