# Android - Handler - How To Stop The Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-handler

I want to stop the delay/intent from processing when the back button is pressed. I've searched some threads but I don't have the same Handler logic, I think. I apologize if it is.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
else {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PollWebView_Gilmore.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                    }

                }, 10000);
```

Comment: If you don't need a delay just remove the Handler and keep only the intent

Comment: code is perfect then whats the problem? please explain your problem

Comment: @AbhishekSingh - I would like to cancel the delay/intent when the user presses back.

Comment: @Charuක - I need the delay to show additional content first. But if the user presses the back button, I wanted the delay/intent to cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save a reference to both the `Handler` and your `Runnable` somewhere, and then you can use the `removeCallbacks(Runnable)` method on the `Handler` to cancel the pending request.

Example code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }

}
```

Comment: how do I put "handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);" inside onBackPressed()?

Comment: I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I already have a function for "onBackPressed();" should I just add this?

Comment: thank you. Got it to work. May I have a contact detail from you? I would also like to ask an additional question about Google Maps.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you with that, but just post your questions here, I'm sure you'll find someone who can.

Answer (score 1):

If you Don't need a delay why do you use a Handler? Just remove it!

Call this directly

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PollWebView_Gilmore.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

When your back button is pressed!

You can also get an idea by reading below posts.

[Android: Proper Way to use onBackPressed() with Toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413700/android-proper-way-to-use-onbackpressed-with-toast)

[How to run a Runnable thread in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android)

Comment: how do I put "handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);" inside onBackPressed()?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something with the intent on back pressed.You can override onBackPressed() method.

Comment: how do I put "handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);" inside onBackPressed()?

Comment: @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }