# Intercept BACK button from soft keyboard When in listView Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, keyboard, back

I have multiple different listView adapters. Each listView adapter has some editText. When user is editing editText, the soft keyboard will show up. I want to update the text in editText when user hit BACK button to dismiss keyboard.

For updating info, I will need to know which adapter class is handling, which position of this editText is editing, and the content of text.

I have googled all the possible solutions. There is one to set up a custom editText class, and override `OnKeyPreIme` function. This solution couldn't get me all the infomation i want above.

Please suggest me some way to intercept BACK button I could implement in the adapter class. Or Which I could easily get the info I want to update.

Answer (score 0):

You can [use `onBackPressed()` from the `Activity`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413700/android-proper-way-to-use-onbackpressed-with-toast) to detect when the user has pressed the back button.

It's not clear what logic you're really after; but the general pattern would be is that when you capture the event, you should be able to assess the states of all the `EditText` resources that can be accessed by your `Activity`. You can use `setText()` and `getText()` to establish the bespoke functionality you're describing.

You may need to determine whether the soft keyboard is open or not when you handle the back button press; i.e, whether you wish to update the fields at all. This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216749/softkeyboard-open-and-close-listener-in-an-activity-in-android) describes a useful mechanism for doing so.