# onBackPressed to home screen

Tags: java, android, onbackpressed

I want to have a condition for the tab when i backpressed it all goes on Home tab but when i backpressed all the activities end.

here's my code. try to help me.

```
 backpressed = true;

   if (results.equals("HOME")) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
        backpressed = false;
    } else if (results.equals("B")) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    } else if (results.equals("C")) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(3);
    } else if (results.equals("D")) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    } else if (results.equals("E")) {

        singleton.openNewsFeed = true;
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(4);
    } else {
        singleton.openMessage = true;
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(4);
    }
```

and this is my onBackPressed

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    /*super.onBackPressed();*/

    if (backpressed == true) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);
        intent.putExtra("result", "HOME"); // getText() SHOULD NOT be static!!!
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        //FINISH
       super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Comment: use this `Your_Activity.super.onBackPressed();` rather than using Intent. refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413700/android-proper-way-to-use-onbackpressed-with-toast

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong condition here

You should try with this

```
 backpressed = false;

   if (results.equals("HOME")) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
        backpressed = true;
    } else if (results.equals("B")) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    } else if (results.equals("C")) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(3);
    } else if (results.equals("D")) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    } else if (results.equals("E")) {

        singleton.openNewsFeed = true;
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(4);
    } else {
        singleton.openMessage = true;
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(4);
    }
```

on back pressed

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    /*super.onBackPressed();*/

    if (backpressed == true) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);
        intent.putExtra("result", "HOME"); // getText() SHOULD NOT be static!!!
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        //FINISH
       //super.onBackPressed();
       mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: not the Home page. the Home screen of android phone is what i was talking about

Answer (score 0):

I can not Understand Clearly what you do from onBackPressed(),

But i think this onBackPressed() code helps you :-

> MainActivity.Java
>
> ```
> //Codes for Exit Dialog Box Starts
>  @Override
>  public void onBackPressed(){
>      AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
>      builder.setMessage("Are You Sure You Want to Exit ?")
>              .setCancelable(false)
>              .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
>                  @Override
>                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
>                      MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
>                  }
>              })
>              .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
>                  @Override
>                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
>                      dialogInterface.cancel();
>                  }
>              });
>      AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
>      alertDialog.show();
>  }
>  //Codes for Exit Dialog Box Ends
> ```